# Is there a default maximum width for html tables rendered in Outlook/Word?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a html table which needs to be sent as an email. It renders as desired on Chrome, IE etc. But I can't crack an issue with the table width in Outlook/Word. I haven't specified any column widths, or max/min widths at any point, the default column widths work perfectly for me (ie. defined by largest word width in col). Yet when the table is rendered in Word, there seems to be some table width cap applied. Some columns are cut off, and the rest are squashed, even to the point that single word headers are separated into multiple lines.

Is there a default table width, or possibly page width, when rendering in Outlook/Word that would explain this?

For context, note that the tables I want to display can be pretty wide, and this is desired. Scrolling across is perfectly fine.

I've attached 2 images of the same html file rendered with both Chrome and Word to demonstrate the issue.

Thanks in advance!

[Image of Chrome Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55fjQ.png)
[Image of Word Rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrRFQ.png)